# How can I create a model by a query interceptor in Data Services? OData

Tags: c#, .net, sql, ado.net, wcf-data-services

I have been looking for an answer the last couple of days to find out, but I could not get any answer, that's why I decided to write here.

The problem is as followed:
I have a data service where the model is beeing created by a data service provider, in this case a reflection provider. Pretty simple. But we want to create the data model with a query interceptor and not using a query interceptor to filter data.

What am I wanting to achieve: /service.svc/search?fromDate=x&toDate=y

I have a model called search, which is a model of search data and search results, the reflection provider would then take the two parameters fromDate and toDate, save them as variables and then throw them in a stored sql procedure as parameters. The searchresult will then be saved in the model.

I find it hard to explain this, since it is not the usual stuff you do with a query interceptor and the reflection provider I guess.

Usually the query interceptor is beeing used and applied to a finished data model to filter out parts of the model.

Does anyone have an idea how to achieve this?

I know how to parameterize a query interceptor - http://ashwini47-tts.blogspot.in/2012/03/how-to-parametrized-queryinterceptor-in.html - but don't know how to send the parameters into the dbcontext/objectcontext.

Comment: An interceptor seems totally the wrong tool here. Why not build a proper model on top of the db?

Comment: Yes, I think so too, but it seemed to easy when we were building this api, but the model which we are trying to show in OData is a model containing search results, I have no idea how I could build such a model on top of the db.

Answer (score 0):

Query interceptors are not meant to solve this problem for you. You have two options:

1) Service operation which takes the two parameters and returns a set of results. Very easy to implement, but you will also need to expose the set of "all" results. Not sure if that's possible for you. There are possible workarounds but they are somewhat complicated and would be more complex than #2 below.

2) Describe the query as an OData query. So something like ~/searchResults?$filter=date gt  and date lt . Then from your searchResults IQueryable property return a custom IQueryable implementation which processes the expression tree, which contains the filter, extracts the from and to values and evaluates the query by running a stored procedure. This is definitely more work, but it's the OData way of querying, is the service operation in #1 doesn't fit your space.

Comment: I was trying the way to use the service operation, but it seems I cannot use Entity Framework then to map the model. But maybe I wasn't looking hardly enough.
Gonna check the way to create a custom IQueryable implementation.

Comment: In the service operation solution use this.CurrentDataSource to get the EF context, that should work just fine.

Comment: Oh, thanks. But what about filters and other built in functions such as $count ? Sorry, I am really new to the data service stuff, I know the basics, but not more :/

Comment: If your service operation returns IQueryable<T> where T is an entity type, then WCF Data Services will let the client apply additional query operators on top of the service operation result. Including $count, $orderby, $filter and so on. You just need to implement the service operation such that it returns an EF query (not the actual results) and WCF DS will build on top of it.

Comment: Ok, I'm gonna give it a try! Will report how it went, thanks!